# Python automatically add import statement

Tags: python

Is there a way to automatically add imports to python code within emacs?

```
def f(x: str) -> List[str]:
```

I want to be able to have my guess over "List" press a key binding and magically add List to my imports.

I had a brief look on github, didn't find much. I found a package called `importless-lang` that was a partial implementation of this idea, and started adpting this by it seemed like a reasonable amount of work.